# Вопрос про значение переменной в цикле

Tags: java, циклы

Есть код. На выводе получается последовательное возведение 2 в степень (10 раз). Но ведь значение переменной res присваивается в цикле, по логике (моей), оно должно каждый раз присваиваться заново, но вместо этого увеличивается. Объясните доступно, пожалуйста, почему так происходит, почему сохраняется результат последнего перемножения.

```
public class Quadro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int e, res;

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            res=1;
            e=i;
            while(e>0){
                res*=2;
                e--;
            }
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оно и присваивается заново. А вот `e` всё время растёт, т.к. `i` растёт. А т.к. `res` на 2 умножается столько раз, каково у нас значение `e`, то в каждой итерации цикла `res` становится больше в 2 раза на момент выхода из текущей итерации.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял)